# Given an x and polynomial equation, is there way to get the y value using r?

Tags: r, solver, polynomials

If I have a equation like `10 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 = y` and an x value like 2. Is there way to plug this into r so it would solve for y? It sounds trivial but eventually I would like to solve for x using polynomials that higher degrees like 30. Anyone know of a possible way to do this in r but without plugging in the x value manually?

Please note: I'm trying to solve for y given a specific x value.

Comment: Is it y you’re trying to calculate or x? If it’s y and you can write out the equation manually just write a function like: poly <- function(x) {return(10 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4)} and then call it for a given x: y <- poly(2) or series of Xs.

Comment: Sorry, it's the y I'm trying to solve. My bad if that wasn't clear.

Comment: OK, does my suggestion work for that?

Comment: That does work, is there a way for me to use polynomial()? I tried to use your suggestion with polynomial() but it didn't work. I would prefer not to write out the polynomial all the way out since it could get too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily write your own function:

```
p <- function(x, coefs) c(cbind(1, poly(x, degree = length(coefs) - 1, 
                            raw = TRUE, simple = TRUE)) %*% coefs)
p(2, c(10, 0, 1, 1, 1))
#[1] 38
```

Use `rep` if you need many coefficients of 1.

Comment: When I run this I get this error: 
'Error in poly(x, degree = length(coefs) - 1, raw = TRUE, simple = TRUE) : 
  unused arguments (degree = length(coefs) - 1, raw = TRUE, simple = TRUE)'

Comment: Nvm! I had a function stored that was messing it up. Thanks!